# CSS Transition is not working at FireFox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

```
 css("transition", "background 0.5s linear")
```

Code above is executed when click event is done which page's background image is transformed A fading out to B fading in.

At Chrome , not only the code above but also all other codes are working well.

But some codes like the one above are not working at some browsers, especially,

1. FireFox
2. IE

What problem am I missing now?

Comment: why don't you create a new class with the mentioned `transition` and add that class name using 'addClass'

Comment: `page's background image is transformed` is background-image even animatable?

Comment: as far as i can see in [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546052) transitions for background-image: a) is a CSS4 thing; and b) not implemented in firefox

Comment: in fact, chrome (maybe safari) seems to be the only browser that has implemented transitions on background images

Comment: @JaromandaX Actually, our thing is css3. And what do you mean that chrome is the only browser implementing transitions on background images? Isn't it belonged to CSS not Chrome?

Comment: `our thing is css3` - I've only seen transitions for background-**image** referred to in css4, not css3. `Isn't it belonged to CSS not Chrome?` what? there is CSS specifications, not all browsers implement the whole of the specification (much like ES2015 or HTML5 specs, not all browsers support 100% of those either) ... as far as transitions on background-**image** it appears that only chrome has implemented that CSS feature (doesn't make it a chrome thing, it's still CSS)

Comment: Wow, you look like a specialist at CSS, thank you I'll need to focus on what you told me and survey too!

Comment: @JaromandaX  So what you mean is that firefox doesn't implement transition so at firefox, it doesn't work right? So what could be the solution to solve it? It's my guess 1) Recognize the browser user is using 2) specifying the browser and implement it differently right?

Comment: I'm saying chrome is apparently the only browser that has implemented animations/transitions on background-**image** ... I've not said anything about transitions in firefox in general - and yes, there are workarounds

Comment: @JaromandaX Acoording to this link : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp , Firefox also functions 'transition' , isn't it?

Comment: @kyungmoon.lee - you seem to have difficulty in understanding why I make reference to background-**image** with **image** bold ... I **never** said firefox hasn't implemented transitions ... I said it hasn't implemented transitions on background-**image** (transitions on other background properties like colour for example ARE implemented in firefox) ... as for w3schools, that site is widely considered a bad joke, so I take no stock in what they say regardless

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed css Prefixes.
Your can find more details from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

**Typically the vendors use these prefixes:**

-webkit- (Chrome, newer versions of Opera.)

-moz- (Firefox)

-o- (Old versions of Opera)

-ms- (Internet Explorer)

So You should add transition code with css prefix.

Comment: What does 'browser vendor' mean at the link of you added?

Comment: In Firefox "-moz-transition". In chrome -webkit-transition. In IE -ms-transition

Comment: yes, use them. Actually these, like -mox-, -webkit- create a type of hack to targetting a unique browser

Comment: Here Some more details. [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp)

Comment: firefox hasn't needed the -moz- prefix for transitions since version 16.0, chrome hasn't needed the -webkit- prefix since version 26.0, safari since version 6, opera hasn't needed the -o- prefix since version 12.10, Internet Explorer never used the -ms- prefix for transitions

Answer (score -1):

Instead of apply css with jquery, add a class:

```
 .addClass("class-name")

.class-name {
    transition: background 0.5s linear;
}
```

Comment: how does this enable background image transitions in firefox and ie?

Comment: Because sometimes works better applying classes then use css in jquery.

Comment: Transition on background images is only implemented in webkit.